# Trying to use a for loop to solve an equation and then loading it into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So, this is my code. I want it to take the answer for each item in the array and load it into a new array once the answer is found. However, it is only solving the question for the first number in the array and then adding that answer to the array multiple times. I hope that makes sense.

```
var crosswindarray = [] as! [String]

func crossWindCalculation() {
    var runwayNames = ["28", "36"]
    for runwayNumbers in runwayNames {
        var windSpeedInt = 20
        var runwayHeadingString = runwayNumbers
        runwayHeadingString.removeLast()
        runwayHeadingString.append("0")


        let crossWindSin: Float = Float(sin(50 * Double.pi / 180))
        let crossWindAnswer: Float = crossWindSin * Float(windSpeedInt)
        crosswindarray.append(String(format: "XW: %.f", crossWindAnswer))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you are saying `var crosswindarray = [] as! [String]` each time through the loop. So you make a new empty array every time.

Comment: And then, having appended a value to this empty array, you throw the array away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're making a new array each iteration of the loop - make an array scoped to the whole function:

```
func crossWindCalculation() {
  var crosswindarray = [] as! [String]
  for runwayNumbers in runwayNames {
    // ...
    let crossWindAnswer: Float = crossWindSin * Float(windSpeedInt)
    crosswindarray.append(String(format: "XW: 5.f", crossWindAnswer))
  }
  // Do something with crosswindarray
}
```